# play video on server on client web browser using byte stream

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to play an video in web browser.
The below html code is working fine in Google crome but does not work in IE and firefox.
I am getting an .avi file from c:/ on server and conveting it into byte stream and sending the bytes as responce.

enter code here

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <object id="MediaPlayer" width="192" height="146" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" standby="Loading Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject">
    <param name="SRC" value="dg">                
    <param name="ShowControls" value="false">
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
    <param name="autostart" value="true">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="http://125.60.35.36:8888/sa/jsp/common/showVideo.jsp?path=library/2013/Video/sample_1362996503283.avi" name="MediaPlayer" width="400" height="300" showcontrols="1" showstatusbar="0" showdisplay="0" autostart="0"> 
   </object>
   </body>
   </html>
```

enter code here

```
String filePath = "c:/sa/documents/"+request.getParameter("path");
System.out.println(filePath);
InputStream is=new FileInputStream(filePath);
OutputStream os=response.getOutputStream();
//OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("c:/test.avi");
byte b[]=IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
os.write(b,0,b.length);
os.close();
is.close();
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you should *definitely* sanitize `request.getParameter("path")` before using it, or a malicious user could acquire the bytes of **any** file on your web server.

Comment: Vulcan thanks for your reply, Can you please let me know how can I sanitize request.getParameter("path"). And let me know how can I play the video in IE and firefox. The video gets play in Google Crome but not in IE and FF